# 'Cannot resolve symbol mGoogleApiClient' - Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm writing an app with AndroidStudio, I wanted to integrate it with Google+ login, so I used tutorial.

On my LoginActivity is this code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
(...)
```

on build gradle I have:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

(...)

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

And still, at the LoginActivity I get "Cannot resolve symbol mGoogleApiClient.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to declare it like this before the onCreate()

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
```

Comment: check it as an answer

Comment: @mazabin You should accept the answer if you found it helpful, helps the answerer as well as people who come to this post in the future !!

Comment: I'm sorry. I upvoted, but  forgot to accept. Now it should be fine. :)